# How do you programatically set grid scale?

Tags: scripting

The python tooltip says to use

```
bpy.data.screens["Scripting"].overlay.grid_scale = n
```

but that doesn't work. There are no other commands that execute when I do it manually. So it's just that command. Except when I do it programmatically it doesn't work (`AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'overlay'`). This pictures sums up the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is trying to inform you that the property lookup `<screen>.overlay` was unsuccessful, because that's not where that property is located *(the tooltip is misleading..)* . It's something you might want to iterate through screen `area.spaces` to locate and set. It's a little awkward, but acceptable.

```
import bpy

AREA = 'VIEW_3D'

for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    for area in window.screen.areas:
        if not area.type == AREA:
            continue

        for s in area.spaces:
            if s.type == AREA:
                s.overlay.grid_scale = 2
                break
```

or..

```
import bpy
for area in bpy.data.screens["Scripting"].areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for space in area.spaces:
            if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                space.overlay.grid_scale = 2
                break
```

Comment: NICE! Thank you.